# Normal distribution inequality

Tags: normal-distribution, inequality

I came across a theorem that involves inequality in a normal distribution:
For $z> 0$, the function $\Phi \left ( z \right )$ satisfies the inequality 
$$\left ( \frac{1}{z}-\frac{1}{z^{3}} \right )\phi \left ( z \right )\leq 1-\Phi \left ( z \right )\leq \frac{1}{z}\phi \left ( z \right )
$$
Notes: $\phi \left ( z \right )= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi }}e^{\frac{-z^{2}}{2}}$ is the density and $\Phi \left ( z \right )= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi }}\int_{-\infty }^{z}e^{\frac{-z^{2}}{2}}dz$ is the cdf. 
So how to prove this? Efforts have been made to search for answers to similar questions but those are not quite relevant to what I am looking for. Thanks in advance!

Comment: None of the answers to the questions listed above give a proof of the lower bound though sone do provide a proof of the upper bound. For an elementary derivation of both bounds, see [this answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/69417/15941) over on math.SE.

Comment: @DilipSarwateThat is what I was looking for. Thanks Dilip!

Comment: @DilipSarwate I did have one question about the last equation in your comment to Thor H. Jonsson (sorry I don't have enough reputations to follow up a comment there). I suppose there should be a negative sign in front of $\frac{1}{t}e^{-\frac{t^{2}}{2}}$? Also, the reason why $- \frac{1}{t}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-t^2/2)\biggr\vert_x^\infty 
= \frac{\phi(x)}{x}$ is because the integral was from x to $\infty$ instead of from $-\infty$ to x and so the negative signs got cancelled?